# How to get elements of form as array

Tags: php, html

How can collect form elements of a particular field set as array dynamically using fm_id.serialize()
My code:-

```
  <form id="registration_form">
  <fieldset id="myFieldset1" name="">
  Name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
  Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
  Place: <input type="text" name="place"><br>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="myFieldset2" name="">
   Email: <input type="text" name="usermail"><br>
   Job: <input type="text" name="job"><br>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Am sliding these fieldsets on click next button in a form.I need to fetch each fieldset values as an array on button click to submit the fieldset value

Comment: Do you want it in client side ?

Comment: yes in client side

Answer (score 0):

In js you may get form as array like this

```
var form = document.registration_form;
//get form data
var data = $(form).serializeArray();
```

Comment: i do not want elements entire form as array, need a particular fieldset as arrays .In this example i need two arrays of two fieldsets

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize Fieldsets just fine.

```js
$("#myFieldset1").change(function(){
  $("#out").text($("#myFieldset1").serialize());
});
$("#myFieldset2").change(function(){
  $("#out").text($("#myFieldset2").serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="registration_form">
  <fieldset id="myFieldset1" name="">
  Name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
  Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
  Place: <input type="text" name="place"><br>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="myFieldset2" name="">
   Email: <input type="text" name="usermail"><br>
   Job: <input type="text" name="job"><br>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```